# Match 3 games made with JavaScript and React run slowly on Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using javascript, react, node.js, and mongoDB to create a match 3 game that opens as a webview on top of a React-Native based app.
Since most of the calculation logic is handled in the front end, it works too slowly on Android.
Does anyone know how to solve it?
(i tapped unity engine, it was not working on RN)

Sorry for not attaching the code as it is too big.

Comment: You probably *did something wrong™* in your code, which you'll need to *fix*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.